# Why this oddity when using nmap?

Tags: networking, routing, nmap

My home router (Mikrotik RB750Gr2) has an internal IP address of `192.168.1.1` and a routing table which looks like this:

```
#      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          174.67.140.1              1
1 ADC  174.67.140.0/23    174.67.141.204  ether1                    0
2 ADC  192.168.0.0/16     192.168.1.1     bridge1                   0
```

From my desktop PC (`192.168.1.10`, if it matters) I ran nmap to scan my whole `/16` network, but it seems to have tried to scan 192/8.

What did I do wrong?

```
ron@haggis:~$ sudo nmap -A -T4 192.168/16
[sudo] password for ron: 

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-16 23:01 CST
Warning: 192.0.7.15 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
Warning: 192.0.7.24 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
Warning: 192.0.8.33 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
[snip]
Warning: 192.0.5.61 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
Warning: 192.0.5.154 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (6).
^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nmap doesn't support abbreviating the IPv4 address that way. You must include all four octets: `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: Ok.  How then is it interpreting `192.168/16`?

Comment: @RonJohn It's an unsupported input format and its parsing behavior is undefined for that. I would guess no one's ever really looked into how the parsing code would mishandle that; the authors knew it wouldn't work and documented that you need all four octets. If you're morbidly curious to know what it does, I suppose you could walk through the parsing code yourself.